# Why my text box is not correctly initialized when the datacontext is an list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Hero class. It has only one property Name and it implemented the interface about the changes.

```
public class Hero : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
 {
     public string Name { get { return _name; } 
         set
         {
             _name = value;
             if (PropertyChanged != null)
             {
                 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
             }
             if (CollectionChanged != null)
             {
                 CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace));
             }
         }
     }
    private string _name = "";
}
```

My xaml is follows. I bind the text's datacontext to a collection named Heros which is defined in back code.

```
<Window x:Class="Chap21_2.TestCollection"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="TestCollection" Height="640" Width="480"
     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" DataContext="{Binding Heros}"></TextBox>
       <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="aa" ></Button>
  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

And here're my back code. It initlialize the collection, the problem is when the Init() order is changed, the result is different.

```
public partial class TestCollection : Window
 {
     public ObservableCollection<Hero> Heros { get { return _heros; } set { _heros = value; } }

    private ObservableCollection<Hero> _heros = new ObservableCollection<Hero>();


     public TestCollection()
     {
         // If move Init() here, it'll works.
         InitializeComponent();
         Init();   
     }

    void Init()
     {
         Hero hero = new Hero("Bu Lv", 100, 88, 100, 30);

        _heros.Add(hero);
         hero.HP = 88;

        hero = new Hero("Fei Zhang", 100, 88, 100, 30);
         hero.HP = 90;
         _heros.Add(hero);
     }
 }
```

When I start my code , the text box isn't display "Bu Lv" I expected.
 But If I move Init() before InitializedComponent(), it works.
 Why?

Comment: Well for starters you don't need to implement collection changed on a class that only has a string property. I'm also not sure why you are setting the datacontext to a self binding in xaml, it would be easier to simply set DataContext = this; in code-behind after you initialize component if that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to binding a collection to a single textbox. If I change it to use an ItemsControl, the Init can be after InitializeComponent. Here are the things I did.

#### Hero.cs

```
public class Hero : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _name = string.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
       get { return _name; }
       set
       {
          _name = value;
          if (PropertyChanged != null)
          {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
          }
       }
    }
}
```

#### TestCollection.xaml

This includes your original with some changes for illustration purposes.

```
<Window x:Class="Chap21_2.TestCollection"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="TestCollection" Height="640" Width="480"
     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- Your original binding -->
      <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" DataContext="{Binding Heros}" />
      <!-- My added ItemsControl for example purposes -->
      <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Heros}">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>

      <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="aa" ></Button>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### TestCollection.xaml.cs

Your example didn't include all of the other properties, so I commented them out for the purpose of this example.

```
public partial class TestCollection : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<Hero> Heros { get { return _heros; } set { _heros = value; } }
  private ObservableCollection<Hero> _heros = new ObservableCollection<Hero>();

  public TestCollection()
  {
     // Putting this here allows the collection to populate BEFORE the UI is initialized.
     // Init(); 
     InitializeComponent();
     // Putting it here is normal. The ItemsControl works, but the single TextBox binding will not.
     Init();
  }

  private void Init()
  {
     Hero hero;
     //Hero hero = new Hero("Bu Lv", 100, 88, 100, 30);
     //hero.HP = 88;
     hero = new Hero();
     hero.Name = "Bu Lv";
     _heros.Add(hero);

     //hero = new Hero("Fei Zhang", 100, 88, 100, 30);
     //hero.HP = 90;
     hero = new Hero();
     hero.Name = "Fei Zhang";
     _heros.Add(hero);
  }
}
```

My suggestion is that if you are wanting to display a single model from a collection, you may want to add a "SelectedHero" or similar property that contains only a single Hero instance. A collection bound to something is usually meant to render all instances in the collection.

Either way you look at it, you can put the Init() before or after IntializeComponent() because you are not directly interacting with the UI.

Comment: Thanks Chris. How about bind to a combobox? I found if I put the Init() before InitializeComponent(), the combobox will select the first record automatically. But if I put the Init() after InitializeComponent(), it will not select any record. The xaml code is follows:<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Heros}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"></ComboBox>. Any suggestions?

Comment: @System I don't know why it didn't notify me about your comment, but I saw it while going through my list. The reason it doesn't select anything when `Init()` is after `InitializeComponent()` is because the control is initialized with an empty collection. In my forms, there is a master ViewModel that has all of the form's DependencyProperties. This includes various ObservableCollections. The `SelectedIndex` gets bound to one of the properties. Then, it's just a matter if initializing the index after population. Since you don't have such a binding, you'll need to access it directly.

Comment: If you place `Init()` after, then you can programatically select it. Add a name to your ComboBox, like `<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" x:Name="cboHeroes" ItemsSource="{Binding Heros}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />`, and then you can select it like this: `cboHeroes.SelectedIndex = 0;`. Alternately, make a master ViewModel for your form and use DependencyProperties to bind OneWay or TwoWay.

Comment: Keep in mind my note about "not directly interacting with the UI." If you do want to do a code-behind `SelectedIndex` change, it _must_ be after `InitializeComponent()`. It also assumes that the collection has content.